# String Interpolated base url and end point not working on Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

I have implemented a flutter web app and created develop and release environments. I am accessing the API Url like  `"${ConfigEnv.baseUrl}${MyEndPointFile.jokesEndPoint}",` .
The Config File looks like below:

```
class ConfigEnv{
   static String get fileName {
    if(kReleaseMode){
      return '.env.production';
    }
    return '.env.develop';
  }

  static String get baseUrl{
    return dotenv.env['API_URL'] ?? '';
  }
}
```

When I run my web app locally in develop mode or release mode then the correct base urls are picked as written in .env file but when I host the web app to custom domain then the base url is getting replaced by the domain name of my hosted web app.
To simplify and debug the problem, when I replace the interpolated string (baseUrl+endPoint) by complete hardcoded API URL then it is working  on deployed live website as well.
Why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide more debugging details. For example, how is the webapp fetching the env file?

Comment: My .env file has the API base URK for develop and similar another .env for production API base URL. For example: my .env.production looks like API_URL = https://testproduction-api-929265sb5q-uc.a.app.

Comment: To simplify and debug the problem, when I replace the interpolated string (baseUrl+endPoint) by complete hardcoded API URL then it is working on deployed live website as well. * This hardcoded url i wrote in simple dart file where my api request is written like http.get('my_ap_url') in controller.

Comment: Have you tried printing the value to the browser console in your 'production' mode to see if it's right or wrong? In production, where is the "env" file stored?

Comment: Yes I tried printing the env variable on UI in localhost by running command flutter run --release and it is printing correct value on my UI.      // Text("Loaded .env file: ${ConfigEnvironment.baseUrl}"), and my .env files are in the root (the same hierarchy in which the android folder/ios folder/ lib folder resides)